# Using WebKit.NET to browse a .htaccess protected page

Tags: c#, .htaccess, webkit.net

I'm using WebKit.NET in a C# application on Win7 (32bits) to realize a kiosk application. The web pages I'd like to browse are protected by .htaccess file.

So the first loading is ok when I enter the url http://mylogin:mypasswd@mywebsite.com/index.php
But when I click any link the WebKit Browser doesn't memorize the credentials.

**Authorization Required**
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Anyone have an idea of how to fix it ? And / Or more precisely how to set the webKitBrowser.Url.UserInfo ?

Thanks in advance